# Get affected rows count after sqlite transaction

Tags: c, sqlite

How can I get the affected row count after a Sqlite transaction - containing many updates?

I am using the C api.

Comment: Maybe this is dum, but can't you just sum each sqlite3_chances() for each query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sqlite3_changes() functon](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) returns only the row count of the *last* UPDATE statement.

To get the affected row count of all statements in a transaction, call [sqlite3_total_changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/total_changes.html) before and after the transaction, and compute the difference.

Comment: Sounds very interesting, but I guess there might exist some troubles like threading **If a separate thread makes changes on the same database connection while sqlite3_total_changes() is running then the value returned is unpredictable and not meaningful.** I think I'm gonna mark this as correct anyway cause I guess there isn't any better solution. I was gonna use this for debug purposes anyway and not business logic.

Comment: If you had multipe threads sharing *the same* database connection, you would have worse problems. There is no problem if each thread has its own connection.